# My Windows Phone app crashes when download from store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

My application runs normally on the emulator without any problems.
But when I upload it to the app store and download it from the app store it crashes.

I've started by  debugging and the app doesn't crash. It only crashes when downloaded to the phone from the store.

Note: I uploaded the app to the store as beta.

Comment: Did you check the stacktrace of the exception? Pop up the message box in App.xaml.cs file's Application_UnhandledException event. Stacktrace will be available in "e.ExceptionObject". Kindly update your question, else it might get removed for not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint to Application_UnhandledException method located in App.xaml.cs and debug e object. If you cannot find anything, put a messagebox in it and publish it to the store as a private beta. Then test it again.

```cs
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
 {
       MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.Message);
 }
```

If you record video then you should add needed capabilities from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx) to your app from AppManifest file.

`ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA` , `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB` and `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE`

Comment: thank you but the app give me error " attempted to perform an unauthorized operation "

Comment: Do you try to access media library in your windows phone app ?

Comment: If you try to record a video got to properties and AppManifest and enable  the capabilities required for video recording

Comment: ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA and ID_CAP_MICROPHONE

is added my app before

Comment: I don't know what you do in your app needs permission else, try allowing everthing and check whether it is work. I think you forget an extra permission. Maybe ID_CAP_MEDIALIB or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I have to solve the problem
The only problem is that you need to define this line

MICROPHONE=MICROPHONE.Default;

Thank all